How do I turn off active window animation when switching workspaces? Ubuntu 24.04
When I switch workspaces, a frame animation appears on the active window, how can I disable it? I'm switching workspaces with key combinations (Alt-1, Alt-2, Alt-3, Alt-4).
Orange border
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uUQcwM6bZiAyRrwndrzu8qx0ly7yCyWl/view?usp=sharing

That took over a min to load and can not see what you wanted anyone to see. All I see is an ask a question page

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When I change workspaces, an orange highlight appears on the active window (in this case, on the terminal on the right side of the screen in the video). I need to remove it without disabling all Ubuntu animations.

I solved it by disabling Enhanced Tiling in Ubuntu Desktop.

On Ubuntu 24.04, you don’t need to disable the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant entirely. Instead, simply set Active Window Hint to Disabled to achieve the desired effect.
